# SAPUI5 - OpenUI5 - Switch workset items in a shell

Tags: sapui5

In a shell, I would like to switch current workset item to another one (in the same shell), as result of pressing a button in the first workset item.
I tried this:

```
press: function(oEvent) {
  var mainShellRef = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("mainShell");
  var datasetRef = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("dataSetId");
  mainShellRef.setContent(datasetRef);
}
```

where `dataSetId` is the workset item in which I would like to go after pressing this button.
The problem anyway is that the workset actually changes, but the header remains the same of the previous one.

I get the same result if I use `mainShellRef.fireWorksetItemSelected({...})`.

Is there a better way to perform this action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `setContent` only is not enought, so this solves the problem:

```
press: function(oEvent) {
  var mainShellRef = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("mainShell");
  var datasetRef = sap.ui.getCore().getElementById("dataSetId");
  mainShellRef.setSelectedWorksetItem("navStoreSubList");
  mainShellRef.setContent(datasetRef);
}
```

where `navStoreSubList` is the id of the workset item (NavigationItem control) in which I want to go.